# Product of two nonnegative real sequences converges to 0. Can we deduce that the smaller sequence converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{c_n\}$ and $\{d_n\}$ be two sequences of real numbers such that for all $n\ge 0$ we have  $c_n\ge d_n\ge 0$. Suppose $c_nd_n\to 0$. If $\{c_n\}$ is unbounded can we prove that $d_n\to 0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Use the definition of convergence. This problem has a fairly straightforward start. Show us what you have done so far, and we can help fill in any gaps.

Comment: Can use: $d_n \le \sqrt{c_n d_n}$

Comment: How do you conclude $d_n$ is bounded? Please improve your post by clicking "Edit" above, not by elaborating in the comments.

Comment: I see. It is straightforward by the squeeze theorem. I forgot to use that both sequences are nonnegative. Thanks.